# How to send data between tabs as activities?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this parent tab from which I want to send a boolean value to one of my tabs. How do I do it? I this the following would work, but obviously it doesn't!

Here's the parent tab (IncludeTabActivity.java):

```
Intent i = getIntent();

i.putExtra("FromMyActivity", fromLogin);

        TabActivity ta = (TabActivity) IncludeTabActivity.this;
        ta.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(0);
```

Here's the child tab:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean fromLogin = extras.getBoolean("FromMyActivity");
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("DefaultSettings", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("FromMyActivity", fromLogin);
editor.commit();
```

then to get it use

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("DefaultSettings", 0);
boolean fromLogin = settings.getBoolean("FromMyActivity", defaultFromLoginValue);
```

Comment: I set the defaultFromLoginValue to false but fromLogin is true in putBoolean. It still gives me false for fromLogin after getBoolean

Comment: Are you making sure to commit the edits before you try to get the boolean?

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would receive the data is sleightly different.

```
Intent received = getIntent();
boolean dataReceived = received.getExtra("FromMyActivity");
```

Comment: The method getExtra(String) is undefined for the type Intent

Comment: because it's getStringExtra(String, defaultValue)

Comment: How can you getStringExtra when you want a boolean to be returned?